# <jQuery> bx slider custom pagers with controls

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have custom paginations that are image files. Normally they stays gray, but once clicked, the clicked one changes its color to green.

I'd like to make 2 things happen **when I click 'next' button(control)** on my bx-slider.

1. slide moves to the next page.
2. corresponding pager icon of the displayed slide turns into **green** while other icons remain gray.

Linking the controls with the bx-slide was easy, but I can't seem to link the custom pagination with the controls. Custom pager works fine when it's clicked and pagination works fine when it's clicked as well. But I cannot connect these two to work simultaneously.

I've tried 2 jQuery codes to achieve this task, but none works. Please see below.

**jQuery #1**
Event happening here is '**click**'. Once 'next' button is clicked, I want to find the index number of the slide being displayed, save it in a variable idx, and click the child(tag) of the pager that has the corresponding index number.

```
$('.bx-next').on('click', function(){
    var idx=$('.benefit-slider li').find("[aria-hidden='false']").index(this);
    $('#slidePager li').eq(idx).children().on('click');
};
```

**jQuery #2**
    In this code, the event is **changing the attribute of the pager**. When the 'next' button is clicked, I want to save the index number of the slide being displayed in variable idx2. Then, if the index number of the slide being displayed matches 0, corresponding image becomes color (Notice color icon ends with -c while gray icon ends with -g).

```
$('.bx-next').on('click', function(){
    var idx2 = $('.benefit-container li').index(this);

    if($('.benefit-container li').eq(idx2)==0){
        $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-c.png');
        $('.b-location').attr('src','/img/benefit-location-g.png');
        $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');
        $('.b-cs').attr('src','/img/benefit-cs-g.png');
    };
    else if($('.benefit-container li').eq(idx2)==1){
        $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-g.png');
        $('.b-location').attr('src','/img/benefit-location-c.png');
        $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');
        $('.b-cs').attr('src','/img/benefit-cs-g.png');
    };
    else if($('.benefit-container li').eq(idx2)==2){
        $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-g.png');
        $('.b-location').attr('src','/img/benefit-location-g.png');
        $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-c.png');
        $('.b-cs').attr('src','/img/benefit-cs-g.png');
    };
    else if($('.benefit-container li').eq(idx2)==3){
        $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-g.png');
        $('.b-location').attr('src','/img/benefit-location-g.png');
        $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');
        $('.b-cs').attr('src','/img/benefit-cs-c.png');
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- CUSTOM PAGER -->

<div class="benefit-container-wrap">
    <ul id="slidePager">
        <li class="b-conts1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/benefit-lowcost-c.png" class="b-cost">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="b-conts2">
             <a href="#">
                 <img src="img/benefit-location-g.png" class="b-location">
             </a>
        </li>
        <li class="b-conts3">
             <a href="#">
                 <img src="img/benefit-logistic-g.png" class="b-logistic">
             </a>
        </li>
        <li class="b-conts4">
             <a href="#">
                  <img src="img/benefit-cs-g.png" class="b-cs">
             </a>
        </li>                
    </ul>                    
</div>


<!-- BX SLIDER -->

<div class="benefit-container col-sm-7 col-md-6">
    <ul class="benefit-slider">
        <li>
            <h3 class="b-cost">Competitive Price</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h3 class="b-location">Optimal Location</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h3 class="b-logistic">Total Logistic Solution</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
             <h3 class="b-customer">Outstanding Customer Services</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Load Bx-Slider jQuery

```
// load bx-slider//
$('.benefit-slider').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom:'#slidePager',
    controls: true
});


//BxSlider custom pager //
$('.b-conts1').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-c.png');
    $('.b-location').attr('src','/img/benefit-location-g.png');
    $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');
    $('.b-cs').attr('src','/img/benefit-cs-g.png');
});
$('.b-conts2').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-g.png');
    $('.b-location').attr('src','/img/benefit-location-c.png');
    $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');
    $('.b-cs').attr('src','/img/benefit-cs-g.png');
});
$('.b-conts3').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-g.png');
    $('.b-location').attr('src','/img/benefit-location-g.png');
    $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-c.png');
    $('.b-cs').attr('src','/img/benefit-cs-g.png');
});
$('.b-conts4').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.b-cost').attr('src','/img/benefit-lowcost-g.png');
    $('.b-location').attr('src','/img/benefit-location-g.png');
    $('.b-logistic').attr('src','/img/benefit-logistic-g.png');
    $('.b-cs').attr('src','/img/benefit-cs-c.png');
});
```

**Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.**

Comment: Can you post the jQuery part of your code where you load bxSlider?

Comment: @zer00ne I uploaded the jQery part of the bxSlider load and linked custom pager.

Answer (score 0):

## [**bxSlider API**](https://bxslider.com/options/)

---

#### **pagerCustom:** *String* - "`{jQuery/CSS Selector}`"

**Demo:** **`pagerCustom: "#bx-pager"`**

Each child (direct descendant element) of the designated custom pager must have this `data-*` attribute:

```
data-slide-index="{Number}"
```

**Demo:** **`<a data-slide-index="0" href="#/" class='active'>...`**

*See comments in Demo for details*

---

#### **onSlideBefore:** *Function Object* - `{functionName}`

**Demo:** **`onSlideBefore: bxMove`**

A callback function invoked on `SlideBefore` API event. This event occurs before a slide transitions to the destination slide.

***Note:*** the `()` from the `functionName` value has been omitted. This is because the callback property is using the function (i.e. `bxMove()`). Had there have been a need for the `return` value of the `function`, then `functionName()` would be used instead.

*See comments in Demo for details*

---

#### **goToSlide():** *Number* - `{0-index count}`

**Demo:** **`bx.goToSlide({index})`**

API method that given an index number, it will execute a transition to the slide that is at the given indexed position. The `bxSliderObject` should be invoked using dot notation:

```
{bxSliderObject}.goToSlide(2);
```

The `bxSliderObject` should be instantiated when loading the plugin:

```
var/const {bxSliderObject} = $("{selector}").bxSlider(...
```

*See comments in Demo for details*

---

#### Miscellaneous

**Demo:** `<a data-slide-index="0" href="#/" class='active'>...`

The `.active` class is applied to `#bx-pager a` for style changes that indicate the current slide index position.

*See comments in Demo for details*

---

### Demo

```js
/*~~~~~~
line no#
|08| Store bxSlider instance in a variable
|10| Callback function bxMove() invoked on SlideBefore event
*/ //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

$(function() {
  const bx = $('#bx-slider').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
    onSlideBefore: bxMove
  });

  /*~~~~~~
  line no#
  |24| [API Callback][onSlideBefore] has default parameters.
  ==== $ele: jQuery Object of the destination element.
  ==== from: index number of departing position. (Not used)
  ==== to..: index number of destination position.
  |25| [API Method][goToSlide()] Pass index, it will jump to it. 
  |26| Remove .active class from all pager links.
  |27| Add .active class to the destination slide element.
  */ //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  function bxMove($ele, from, to) {
    bx.goToSlide(to);
    $('#bx-pager a').removeClass('active');
    $ele.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#bx-pager {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto .75em
}


/* Apply greyscale to all img in pager */

#bx-pager img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#bx-pager a {
  display: table-cell;
}

#bx-pager a.active {
  outline: 3px ridge tomato;
}


/* Decrease greyscale to 0% to the img nested within active link */

#bx-pager a.active img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SO50136244</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <!-- [API Pager][pagerCustom]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> On a custom pager, each link element of the designated pager...
  pagerCustom: "#bx-pager"
  LINK: $("#bx-pager a")
  
>...must have a special data-* attribute:
  data-slide-index="${Number}"
  
> Add .active class to the first pager link. 

< See line no# 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <nav id="bx-pager">
    <a data-slide-index="0" href="#/" class='active'>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/31" width="50" /></a>
    <a data-slide-index="1" href="#/">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/32" width="50" /></a>
    <a data-slide-index="2" href="#/">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/33" width="50" /></a>
    <a data-slide-index="3" href="#/">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/134" width="50" /></a>
    <a data-slide-index="4" href="#/">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/351" width="50" /></a>
    <a data-slide-index="5" href="#/">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/15" width="50" /></a>
  </nav>

  <ul id="bx-slider">
    <li>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/31" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/32" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/33" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/134" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/351" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/15" />
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to change the pager turns into color from gray once it's clicked and the rest remain gray. Only the selected one turns into color. In this case, for your example, it should turn 'gray' from the original color. How do I do that?